# What happens if someone arrives in England with the wrong Covid-19 tests booked?

Tags: uk, england, vaccinations, covid-19

If a person arrives in England by plane and they do not have the correct combination of Covid-19 PCR tests booked, what happens? Will they be given a chance to book the correct tests, and be allowed entry, or just be turned back, or something else?

For example, if someone arrives from an Amber List country with only a day 2 test booked, but due to their vaccination status, should require a day 2 and day 8 test.

Would this person have even been allowed to board the plane or should they have been stopped before boarding? Would they be given a chance to purchase the correct tests in that case?

The government advice is very clear on what tests you need but I can't find any official advice on what would happen if one arrives without the right tests booked.

Comment: Generally the airline will check entry requirements and admissibility during check in . Chances are that if these test bookings are required for admission, the airline will check them and deny boarding if it's insufficient.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.

Comment: I don't agree that the pandemic is "over"! But the question is certainly no longer relevant with the current entry requirements.